# osx - how to programmatically disable USB ports

Tags: macos, usb, security

I'd like to programmatically block, disable or (better) power-off USB ports on my system.

The closest thing I found that resembles or provides such similar control is vmware-usbarbitrator on a guest VM.

I checked online, especially GitHub, for tools that would provide any of these features for a host machine, to no avail.

I want to find a way to generally control access to these ports via software and not resort to sealing or epoxying them.

Needless to mention threats like [BadUSB](https://srlabs.de/badusb/) and such.

Comment: [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59764/how-to-disable-individual-usb-ports-by-script) question indicates its not possible.  [This](http://www.macintouch.com/readerreports/security/topic3177.html) indicates you can delete certain system files and it will disable storage devices, of course, that won't stop BadUSB though. [This](http://images.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/SnowLeopard_Security_Config_v10.6.pdf) goes into more detail which I will let you read yourself.

Comment: In some high-security installations, IT staff physically plug USB port with epoxy... but that precludes use of USB keyboard and mouse. See http://www.techrepublic.com/article/disable-usb-ports-to-prevent-unauthorized-data-transfers/

Answer (score 0):

One of the [links](http://images.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/SnowLeopard_Security_Config_v10.6.pdf) @Ramhound pointed to & this resource at [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2105022?start=0&tstart=0) describe how it can be done. But as said above, it won't stop BadUSB.

Look at the screenshot below for the instructions on how to disable USB

[image: Disable USB Mass storage in Mac OSX]